# Add a new tag with value to an xml file node when its value matches an entry in the text file using shell script

Tags: xml, shell, sed

I am new to shell script. The goal is to add a new sibling node if the  node value is in the txt file.

Here is the xml file: animals.xml

```
<aaa>
   <bbb>123</bbb>
   <ccc>cat</ccc>
   <ddd>dog</ddd>
   </aaa>
<aaa>
   <bbb>456</bbb>
   <ccc>fox</ccc>
   <ddd>bat</ddd>
</aaa>
<aaa>
   <bbb>789</bbb>
   <ccc>rat</ccc>
   <ddd>pig</ddd>
</aaa>
```

Here is the text file: feed.txt

```
123
789
```

The tag to be added is

```
<eee>feed<eee>
```

Given the example above, the animals.xml contents should be updated to

```
<aaa>
   <bbb>123</bbb>
   <ccc>cat</ccc>
   <ddd>dog</ddd>
   <eee>feed</eee>
</aaa>
<aaa>
   <bbb>456</bbb>
   <ccc>fox</ccc>
   <ddd>bat</ddd>
</aaa>
<aaa>
   <bbb>789</bbb>
   <ccc>rat</ccc>
   <ddd>pig</ddd>
   <eee>feed</eee>
</aaa>
```

I tried the following but no luck

```
feed_content="<eee>feed</eee>"
feed_tag=$(echo $feed_content | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
while IFS= read -r f
do
   #Check if there is a <bbb> tag with value equals to f. If there is,append the <eee>feed</eee>
   sed "/<bbb>$f<\/bbb>/ s/.*/${feed_tag}\n&/" $f
done < feed.txt
```

The sed line does not work.It only works if $f is replaced with the actual value. But I cannot do that.

```
sed "/<bbb>123<\/bbb>/ s/.*/${feed_tag}\n&/" $f
```

**Resolved:**

It turns out that $f contains a lot of trailing spaces. I just have to trim it and the sed statement worked.

```
animals_xml=animals.xml
feed_content="<eee>feed</eee>"
feed_tag=$(echo $feed_content | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
while IFS= read -r f
do
   #Check if there is a <bbb> tag with value equals to f. If there is,append the <eee>feed</eee>
   f="${f#"${f%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
   f="${f%"${f##*[![:space:]]}"}"
   sed "/<bbb>$f/ s/.*/&\n\t${feed_tag}/" $animals_xml
done < feed.txt
```

Comment: Don't use line-oriented tools like `sed` to process XML. Use XML-aware tools like `xmlstarlet`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `xmlstarlet`, like this:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s '//bbb[text()='123' or text()='789']/..' \
    -t elem -n eee -u './/eee' -v feed animals.xml
```

If necessary, you can use `sed` to generate the xpath expression from `feed.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str="<eee>feed</eee>"
while read id; do
sed -ri '/<aaa>/{:a;N;/<\/aaa>/!ba;/<bbb>'"$id"'/s#(.*\n)(\s+)([^\n]+\n)#&\2'"$str"'\n#}' animals.xml
done < feed.txt
```